# Parse XML in SQL Server, Return in Table Format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, xpath, sql-server-2012, xquery

The XML looks like this:

```
<Attributes>
<ProductAttribute ID="92">
    <ProductAttributeValue>
        <Value>225</Value>
    </ProductAttributeValue>
</ProductAttribute>
<ProductAttribute ID="536">
    <ProductAttributeValue>
        <Value>227</Value>
    </ProductAttributeValue>
</ProductAttribute>
```

I need

```
ID  - Value
92  - 225
536 - 227
```

In Table Format.

Is it possible to get this values directly from a query or stored procedure or Function?

Comment: [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-sql-server) has an article on XML data and SQL Server, which you might find useful.

Comment: Did you check the docs? They have an entire chapter on storing and parsing XML, queries, transformations etc.  Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: I have checked it but unable to buildup query same as i want result in table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [value()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type) and [nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type) method for xml

```
DECLARE @xml XML = N'<Attributes>
<ProductAttribute ID="92">
    <ProductAttributeValue>
        <Value>225</Value>
    </ProductAttributeValue>
</ProductAttribute>
<ProductAttribute ID="536">
    <ProductAttributeValue>
        <Value>227</Value>
    </ProductAttributeValue>
</ProductAttribute>
</Attributes>'

SELECT ID = x.t.value('(./@ID)[1]','int'),
       Value = x.t.value('(./ProductAttributeValue/Value)[1]','int') 
FROM @xml.nodes('/Attributes/ProductAttribute') AS x(t)
```

Returns

```
ID  Value
---------
92  225
536 227
```